# Using useEffect on several fetch functions causes them to run before a button click, how do I use useCallback instead?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a fetch function to generate an output after pressing a button, this output is then used in several similar fetch functions. To do this I've used useEffect, but the issue is these 2nd and 3rd functions run before I press the button, the button click initiates the first fetch function and once this runs I would only then like the others to run. Otherwise it costs me a lot of money if they're on as soon as the page loads.

I know I should use useCallback, but simply replacing useEffect with useCallback doesn't work of course because it only runs when something is completed. I tried to replace the async function in the 2nd and 3rd functions with useCallBack, like so:

```
    const getOpenAIResponse = async () => {
        openai.createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-003",
            prompt: "Create a unique 1-5 word name.",
            max_tokens: 256,
        }).then((response) => {
            setInputName(response.data.choices[0].text)
            getSlogan()
        })
    };

    const getStory = useCallback (() => {
        openai.createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-003",
            prompt: "Create a story about " + inputName + ".",
            max_tokens: 256,
        }).then((response) => {
            setInputStory(response.data.choices[0].text)
        })
        }, [inputName]);
```

However this did not work, the Story it produced was not based on the inputName - it assumed inputName was blank.

This is my code with useEffect.

```
    const [inputName, setInputName] = useState('');
    const [inputStory, setInputStory] = useState('');
    const [inputDes, setInputDes] = useState('');

    const getOpenAIResponse = async () => {
        openai.createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-003",
            prompt: "Create a unique 1-5 word name.",
            max_tokens: 256,
        }).then((response) => {
            setInputName(response.data.choices[0].text)
        })
    };

    const getStory = async () => {
        openai.createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-003",
            prompt: "Create a story about " + inputName + ".",
            max_tokens: 256,
        }).then((response) => {
            setInputStory(response.data.choices[0].text)
        })
    };

    const getDescription = async () => {
        openai.createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-003",
            prompt: "Create a description for " + inputName + ".",
            max_tokens: 256,
        }).then((response) => {
            setInputDes(response.data.choices[0].text)
        })
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getStory();
        getDescription();
    }, [inputName]);


<Button onClick={getOpenAIResponse}>
```

Once I click the button everything settles down, but before I click it the inputStory and inputDescription are continously running in the background. I only want them to run once the button is clicked, but I need them to depend on the inputName state, so they need to wait for it to finish.

Is there a solution that doesn't run the 2nd and 3rd functions in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a if condition to run the calls when input has values

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(inputName){    
    getStory();
    getDescription();
  }

}, [inputName])
```